# Weird behavior in Chrome (misaligned elements that fix themselves when page is refreshed)

Tags: css

I'm working on a little portfolio website right now and I'm having some trouble with my nav bar.

It works fine in IE and Firefox, but for some reason when it's loaded in chrome the elements don't line up (when the page is refreshed it corrects itself).

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9GOd.png)

[What it looks like in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIHEb.png)

I was wondering what could be causing this and for future reference what would be a good way about debugging a problem like this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first two images are the same link...

Comment: Woops! Fixed the link.

Comment: You can debug it using the developer tools. Right click on an element, click `inspect element`, then look through the html/css and see what's happening.

Comment: You know, I'm not even seeing a difference in Chrome. I'm seeing your top image, "What it should look like". Maybe your css is cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding float left to your image will fix it.

```
#emblem{ 
    float: left
    // other styles
}
```